# How to build for ARMv5 with Gomobile?

Tags: android, go, gomobile

I am trying to replace an existing Go build with Gomobile. However, it seems there is no way to compile for ARMv5 with Gomobile. The old build is doing something like this:

```
export GOARCH=arm
export GOARM=5
go build golang.org/x/mobile/example/bind/hello


gobind {
    pkg = "golang.org/x/mobile/example/bind/hello"
    GOARCH="arm"
}
```

This places the library in armeabi-v7a folder in the apk, which indicates that it is an ARMv7 binary.

[image]

Is there any way to generate an ARMv5 library instead? I tried to set `GOARM=5` in the gobind block of build.gradle, but that results in an error:

```
Could not set unknown property 'GOARM' for object of type org.golang.mobile.GobindExtension.
```

Comment: https://dave.cheney.net/2015/08/22/cross-compilation-with-go-1-5

Comment: My question is specifically about gomobile, but your link is only about normal Go builds.

Comment: have you tried `env GOARCH=arm GOARM=5 go build`?

Comment: I tried that with the `gomobile` command, but it has no effect.